# Error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client while using express

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

ERROR: `[ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`
I have an Express Server( *^4.17.1*) and a MySQL database. This is the code

```
exports.postFormInput = async (req, res, next) => {
 
  jwt.verify(req.body.jwt, process.env.SECRET_FOR_JWT, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) {
      res.sendStatus(403);
      res.end();
    }
    else if (decoded.userId !== req.body.userId) {
      res.sendStatus(403);
      res.end();
      return;
    }
    else {
      username = decoded.username;
      userId = decoded.userId;
    }
  })

  let sql = "SELECT status FROM form_input WHERE user_id = '" + userId + "'";

  try {

    const status = await db.execute(sql);
    status[0].forEach(status1 => {
      if (status1.status == 'processing') {
        return res.json({ message: 'previous result not finished' }).end();

      }
    })
  } catch (e) {
    // return res.status(500);
    next(e);
    return;
  }

const project_name = req.body.ProjectInput.project_name;
  let sql1 = "SELECT project_name FROM form_input WHERE user_id = '" + userId + "'";
  try {
    const project_names = await db.execute(sql1);
    project_names[0].forEach(name1 => {
      if (name1.project_name == project_name) {
        return res.json({ message: 'two projects with the same name' }).end();
      }
    })
  } catch (e) {
    next(e);
    return;
  }
}
```

Error:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:558:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/anurag-gupta/test_del/part1/backend1/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/anurag-gupta/test_del/part1/backend1/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/home/anurag-gupta/test_del/part1/backend1/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
    at exports.get500 (/home/anurag-gupta/test_del/part1/backend1/controllers/error.js:10:7)
    at Layer.handle_error (/home/anurag-gupta/test_del/part1/backend1/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/anurag-gupta/test_del/part1/backend1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:315:13)
    at /home/anurag-gupta/test_del/part1/backend1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/anurag-gupta/test_del/part1/backend1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/anurag-gupta/test_del/part1/backend1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
```

Comment: After you send a response, do a `return` from your function so the following code does not continue to execute and thus try to send another response.

Comment: I added return after all the responses. It doesn't seem to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think if there is an error at the first if statement in your JWT.verify, you do not return the function.

Just try to generate a random number as statuscode, and see which res.send() is sending too early.

Just remember, this error means that you have called res.send() already!

Answer (score 0):

This particular error message occurs when you try to send more than one response to the same request.

There are multiple issues here and they will all have to be fixed before this problem goes away:

1. When you call `res.sendStatus(...)`, do NOT call `res.end()` afterwards.  `res.sendStatus()` sends the whole response, you're done after that.
2. After you send a response, you have to make sure that no more code that can also send a response executes.  In some cases, you can do that with a simple `return` statement, but if you're inside an asynchronous callback and there's other code that can execute outside that asynchronous callback, then you have to do more to make sure that each path through your code can only send one response.
3. You're executing multiple separate asynchronous operations in this function in parallel (`jwt.verify()` and `db.execute()`) so you have no control flow between them and they each have code paths that can send a response (thus multiple responses are sent).
4. You have a `.forEach()` loop that can send a response inside the loop with no particular protection against that loop attempting to send more than one response.